# How to scroll a panel manually?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to use the same functionality available when a Panel.AutoScroll is true, but with the scrollbars invisible.

To do so I need to know how can I scroll to left/right up/down using functions in my code.

Answer (score 13):

You should be able to use the VerticalScroll and HorizontalScroll properties of the component:

```
c.HorizontalScroll.Value += 100;
c.VerticalScroll.Value = c.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
```

Comment: It works only when AutoScroll=true, but then I can't hide the HorizontalScroll/VerticalScroll. Setting the Scroll.Visible=false doesn't hide the scroll)

Comment: Note to anyone who wants to hide the scrollbar like the OP: don't try it.

Comment: Due to a strange bug that I discovered, you'd be better off using `var v = ScrollingPanel.VerticalScroll;v.Value = v.Value = Math.Min(v.Maximum, v.Value + v.LargeChange);` or the scrollbars won't actually move when the panel does. For some reason the value changes back just before it draws the scrollbar, but setting it a second time will update it.

Answer (score 10):

Well if you don't want to use the Autoscroll property, there's a way that I used a long time ago.

- Put a panel inside the panel. Put the scrollbar control on the parent panel, and then use the scrollbar to change the Top property of the panel inside.

It's simple and works beautifully.

Comment: This works better than any other method I've seen, with no code to write.

Comment: Why use a Scrollbar control? Just set the parent Panel to autoscroll.

Comment: Note that Cyril's excellent suggestion requires the height of the child panel to be large enough to view all child controls (were the parent form large enough to show the entire panel).

Answer (score -3):

There's probably a property on the panel to do this, alternatively you can loop through all the panels children and adjust their positions.

Eg. to move all controls 10 px:

```
int xoffset = 10;

foreach(Control c in panel1.Controls)
    c.Location.X += xoffset;
```

The controls can be moved to negative positions to make them move out of the panel, similarly they can have location values bigger than the panels size to make them move out of the panel.

Comment: don't think you can set the location to -ve values.

Comment: fallenidol : That is just plain wrong!  Try it yourself, if you set the .Left property of a control to say -10 it will move left of the border of the container.

Comment: I see I still get downwotes for this answer.  If someone do, please add a comment as to why, as I'm quite curious :)

Comment: I would imagine it's because your suggestion is a horrible, horrible hack - not to mention highly inefficient :)

Comment: @Dan. I would agree that it's inefficient to loop through controls, as opposed to adding all controls to a single panel and adjusting that panels location.  Setting a control's location to a negative offset can not be considererd a "horrible, horrible hack".  How else would you obtain controls moving off left/top border without AutoScroll ?