# Change amount scrollbar moves on a panel

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have a panel with many child controls and with `Autoscroll` enabled. Clicking the arrow at the top or bottom of the scrollbar results in a tiny movement of a few pixels only:

[image: Panel with the down arrow clicked]

Can the amount of movement be controlled and set to a much larger value? Using the .NET Compact Framework.

**EDIT 1**

In the full version of .NET, the `VerticalScroll.SmallChange` and `VerticalScroll.LargeChange` properties can be accessed directly. But these are not available in the Compact Framework. So the question is how to do this in the Compact Framework?

**EDIT 2**
By viewing the panel's `AutoScrollPosition.Y`, I've discovered that the `SmallChange` parameter is set to 5 pixels. This must be the default for `Panel` controls in the Compact Framework. For my touchscreen application, this needs to be something like 70 pixels.

Comment: Doesn't it have `VerticalScroll` property where you can adjust SmallChange and LargeChange?

Comment: Good call. Just checked the full .NET and the `VerticalScroll.SmallChange` and other properties are available programmatically...but these are NOT available in the Compact Framework. So I guess my next step is to find out how to get access to these properties.

Comment: You can also try `VScrollBar` property. You'll need to create a class derived from Panel to access it though, but it should be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I've  come to the conclusion that this is simply not possible in the Compact Framework. This answer is not for the specific question but an excellent workaround adapted from [this answer by Cyril Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262534/how-to-scroll-a-panel-manually)

- Create a new "parent" panel and place the old panel on this parent
- Resize the child so that a small area of the parent is visible. Place `Up` and `Down` buttons on this area.
- Disable `AutoScroll` on the child panel.
- Set the height of the child panel so that the scrollbar disappears. Note that not all of the controls will be visible, of course.
- When one of the buttons is clicked on the parent panel, change the `Top` property of the child.

Works nicely!